# Prove E(XY) < E|XY|

Tags: probability, expectation

I know that for vectors $x'y \leq |x'y|$. But how can this be proved for two random variables which are continuous?

$ E(XY) \leq E|XY|$.

Comment: Expectation is just an integral. It is in general true that $\int_X|f|\ d\mu\geq \int_X f\ d\mu$ for any measure space $(X, \mathcal F, \mu)$.

Comment: ... because $f(\mu) \leq |f(\mu)|$.

Comment: Technically should be $|E(XY)| \leq E|XY|$, in the case $X$ or $Y$ could be negative.

Comment: @Dzoooks There is nothing wrong in writing $E(XY)\leq E(|XY|)$. Of course, integrability of $XY$ is assumed.

Comment: @caffeinemachine  Aha, you are right...  Though, let's be honest, $|E(XY)| \leq E(|XY|)$ is really what the OP means.

Comment: @caffeinemachine and @ David G. Stork: Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $(\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space where $S \subset \mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be a measurable function from $\Omega$ to $\mathcal{S}$, then $X$ and $Y$ are measurable functions. Then $XY$ is measurable and by definition \begin{align}
E(XY) = \int_{\mathcal{S}} XY dP \end{align}Edit: Notice that $\Omega$ may be a space without an order relation, e.g. $\mathbb{C}$. So in general the "inequality" $E(XY) \leq E(|XY|)$ may not hold as  $E(XY)$ may not be able to have an order relation. For example, $E(XY)$ may be a complex number. However, instead by the triangle inequalit y one has \begin{align}  |E(XY)| = |\int_{S} XY dP| \leq \int_{S}|XY| dP = E(|XY|)\end{align} Notice we do not have the problem with order relation as $|E(XY)| \in \mathbb{R}$, which is an ordered field.

Comment: How are we integrating $XY$? $XY$ is not a real valued (or complex valued) function. Or are we assuming $S\subseteq \mathbf R$ (or $S$ is a subset of a Banach space and the integral is Banach space valued)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to state that $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1):

The quantity $|XY|-XY$ is either $2|XY|$ or $0$. So, it is never negative, and therefore its expectation can never be negative.